# И до и после и... Без запятых?

Tags: пунктуация

Журналист и политолог в Редакционном материале сайта пишет, что (условно — они) «сыграли в истории России и до революции и после и в современной России столь значительную роль, что принизить ее не сможет никто».

Отсутствие запятых как-то можно объяснить?

(https://snob.ru/entry/171755?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fzen.yandex.com)

Answer (score 1):

1) Лучше написать так:

...они сыграли в истории России **и до революции и после, и в современной жизни**  столь значительную роль, что принизить ее не сможет никто.

Здесь повторяющийся союз И...И связывает  сочетание ***до революции и после*** и падежную форму ***в современной жизни.***

Повтор слова ***Россия*** лучше исключить.

2) Почему нет запятых?

У автора конструкция ***и до революции и после*** рассматривается как единое сочетание, а дальше следует союз И, отнесенный к падежной форме ***в современной жизни.***

Читается всё это без пауз и перечислительной интонации, которая, видимо, была нежелательна, отвлекала от смыслового центра ***столь значительную роль***.

3) Но в результате получилась **не очень ясная для прочтения графика письма.**

Comment: Получается, первая И — причина? Если убрать её, то всё будет в порядке?

Comment: Нет, первую И нельзя убирать, а то смысл оборота изменится (там значение: как до революции, так и после). Повторяющийся союз И...И отличается от простого И  по смыслу тем, что предполагает, что перечисление является исчерпывающим (информация из Грамматики-80), а здесь даже две пары повторяющихся союзов. Просто задуманную автором фразу трудно понять и правильно прочитать, поэтому лучше поставить запятую, хотя она и требует перечислительной интонации.

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже предложение видится не совсем корректным. Я думаю, дело не только в первой И.

> А во-вторых, евреи сыграли в истории России и до революции и после и в
>   современной России столь значительную роль, что принизить ее не сможет
>   никто.

Первая **И** была бы на месте, если б  смысловое единство **"и до и после"** не было разъединено пояснительным словом **"революции"**. Например, так: *А во-вторых, евреи сыграли в истории России и до и после революции и в современной России столь значительную роль, что принизить ее не сможет никто.*

У Розенталя читаем:

> 2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое
>      единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе
>      пояснительных слов).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=128#pp128

Во-вторых, повтор слова России тоже не создаёт впечатления хорошего качества речи, лучше бы переформулировать:

*А во-вторых, евреи играли и в современной России, и в её истории  и до и после революции столь значительную роль, что принизить ее не сможет никто.*

Comment: Да, зафиксировав произнесённую фразу, часто получаешь не то, что можно прочесть не споткнувшись. Поглаживания по подлежащему не наблюдается.

Comment: Видимо, поэтому публичные высказывания сначала пишутся, а потом читаются по бумажке. А уж если ты корреспондент высокого ранга, будь добр следить за своей речью на публику. Но у нас теперь даже дикторы не пример для подражания, часто делают ошибки, увы...

Comment: Людмила, мне с вашим вариантом некомфортно из-за того, что события перечислены "задом наперед".

Comment: Можно найти другой вариант - но без тавтологии и использования несочетающихся   слов,

Answer (score 1):

Фраза плохо составлена, вопрос лишь в том, что нужно исправить и какой вариант предложить взамен.

1. Уже отмечено Людмилой, что смысловое единство "и до и после" нарушено словом "революции". Тем более нельзя принять отсутствие знаков препинания при трех разнородных словосочетаниях и трижды повторенном союзе *и*.
2. "Повтор слова *России* тоже не создаёт впечатления хорошего качества речи" (Людмила).
3. И еще добавлю от себя: прошедшее время глагола *сыграть* плохо сочетается со словами "современная Россия".

Мой вариант таков:

**А во-вторых, роль евреев как в российской истории — и до революции, и после нее, — так и в жизни современной России столь значительна, что принизить ее не сможет никто.**

Comment: Поезд ушёл, к несчастью, но подытожено хорошо.